# SQL Server 2008 cross domain MSDTC

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, cross-domain, msdtc

I'm using a `TransactionScope` to save data in two different contexts... the database server is in a different domain so I'm getting an exception... does someone know a workarround to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in some network adapter... i tried with a direct connection between two diferent domains and it worked!